# Laravel 4 ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, laravel

I'm trying to make an ajax post in laravel 4, but I'm getting a 500 (Internal Server Error). 
I've looked over the internet and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

My ajax post (executed from 'http://flashwords.dev/app/public/words/level/1'):

```
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://flashwords.dev/app/public/words/post_set',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'JSON',
            data:{
                "words_correct": words_correct,
                "words_false" : words_false
            },
            success:function(){
                console.log("post success");
            }
        });
```

My route:

```
Route::post('words/post_set', array('as'=>'post_set', 'uses'=>'UserController@post_set'));
```

My function in the UserController:

```
public function post_set(){
    $correct = Input::get('words_correct');
    $false = Input::get('words_false');
    var_dump($correct);
}
```

Probably I'm looking over something dumb..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you do `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Are you echoing anything in your controller? I mean a JSON?

Comment: I just did the composer dump-autoload and that doesn't change anything. I don't think I'm echoing a JSON in my controller. I just want to catch the data and use it later on (putting it in my database)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found out the problem.

My code was fine, my url was fine, BUT because I'm trying to post data to my server laravel expect a csrf token sent with the post request.

How? --> http://words.weareloring.com/development/laravel/laravel-4-csrf-tokens-when-using-jquerys-ajax/

It was a security issue.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `url` from:

```
url: 'http://flashwords.dev/app/public/words/post_set',
```

To following:

```
url: 'words/post_set',
```

Hope your controllers are stored in the `app/controllers` folder. You may also use this:

```
url: {{ route('post_set') }}
```

If this is in a `.php` file and using blade, if not blade then remove the `{{}}` and use `echo` instead.

Comment: My controllers are stored in the app/controllers. If I try your solution then I get a 404 because it try to post to http://flashwords.dev/app/public/words/level/words/post_set

Comment: How do you access a normal page (without ajax) ?

Comment: Do you have a `.htaccess` file and are you using `public` in your `url`.

Comment: The ajax post is done on http://flashwords.dev/app/public/words/level/1 which I visit like that in my browser. There is a .htaccess in the public folder but I didn't modified that yet. If I change the route:post to route:get and put an echo in the public function in the UserController than I can visit that page by surfing to http://flashwords.dev/app/public/words/post_set . So for me the route looks fine..

Comment: You have declared the route as `words/post_set` so the url should be `http://flashwords.dev/words/post_set`. From where `words/lavel` came ?

Comment: If you can hit the route using `flashwords.dev/app/public/words/post_set` then your url should be `public/words/post_set`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Route's name to get it's full path and set it to the JSON request:

```
            url:'<?=URL::route('post_set')?>',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'JSON'
            ...stuff
```

I use such style in my own project, and it works just fine.